# Exchange 2007 : Display the email address a sender used instead of the account friendly name

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

In exchange server 2007 when I receive a mail detinate to an alternate email address it just display friendlyName of the account in the To field but i'd like to see the email address it destinated.

A screenshot to better se what I speak about :

[image: Add alternate mail]

[image: To field in outlook]

Like you see, "To" field ("A" in the screenshot) always display Exchange Account it was destinated and so i can't know which email address it was sent to....

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know of to figure out which email Outlook is using to send to other internal Exchange addresses is to double-click on the underlined name in the To: field. This will popup their contact sheet. On the "E-mail Addreses" tab it will list all of their legitimate addresses, including any X400 or X500 addresses they have. Outlook will always use the SMTP address that is bolded ("SMTP:" also known as "Set as Reply address" in the Exchange management tools), and not any of the lower case "smtp:" addresses.

If you want to send mail to someone in Exchange and NOT use their 'primary' address, you'll have to change an Outlook setting. Under Tools -> Options > Preferences -> E-Mail Options -> Advanced E-Mail Options, there is a checkbox for "Automatic name checking". Clearing this box will prevent Outlook from automatically changing any entered SMTP address to the 'friendly' address. This will be changed if you click the Check Names button, though, so be aware of that.